# why my asp.net website doesnt have any styling in the page inspector

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

I'm learning about SEO (Search engine optimization )
I have a website that I created using asp.net everything works just fine but
when I open the page inspector using chrome under network and click on the HTML code I noticed that there is no styling and no images
see picture :

[image: picture]

can someone please explain what's the reason for that and what I can do about it?

for example if i inspect the source of SO the page is fully loaded with all the css and images
[image: SO pciture]

I tried to google it and I didn't find anything useful

Answer (score 0):

[image: Devloper Tool Screenshot]

Click on the area circled with red on the image to get all of the resources like styling(CSS), images etc. You can also click on the individual CSS or the Image button to only see styling or images.

Comment: i edited my question to show what the expected behavior i need

Comment: It is because you have only selected to view the raw html. Try to view other sites then SO to see raw html only.

Answer (score 0):

missing css file? You may go to `CSS` blade to see the details. Opening F12 window then refresh your page.

[image]

Comment: Please correct me if I misunderstood and I will delete my post.